# Как получить фото по api с axios и сохранить его в assets в react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-native, expo

У меня есть api который возвращает фото (https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v11/static/-122.314,37.9242,7.21,0/300x200?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiYWJ1YmFrcnNoIiwiYSI6ImNsaDF0NXo3NzA3Y24zb25wMmViZ3ExbTMifQ.mxkSE9xxV486lzxogWKhdw)

а теперь **надо загрузить это фото локально в приложении react native (expo)**

С api который возвращают json всё понятно, но как **записать это всё в .png или .jpg файл** и сохранить его например в /assets.

С таким родом api работаю впервые. Помогите пожалуйста !

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону [blob](https://learn.javascript.ru/blob)